# will_paginate NoMethodError: undefined method `current_page'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sinatra, will-paginate

I tested my api to get events with will_paginate.

**Test**
while i `run rspec spec/controllers/events_controller_spec.rb:86`
i got the error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `current_page' for #<Event::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f813407acd0>
```

**EventsController.rb**

```
@events = @user.events.where(query, params).page(page).per_page(size).order(:end_date).reverse_order
```

**Error**

from `jbuilder` view part: `json.current_page(@events.current_page)`

It did works before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checked times, the routes are wrong.